# Constrain redundant entries in recursive relation

Tags: database-design

Consider this fictional data model:

[image]

Dudes and Dudettes can have a match.
I would only want a couple to match once.

This would look something similar to this as a table:

```
Dud-ette
id, name
1, Peter
2, Nadine
3, Hans
4, Elle
5, Zoe

Match
id1, id2, time
1, 5, 2022-09-01
2, 3, 2022-09-03
3, 2, 2022-09-03
4, 3, 2022-08-24
```

Now see what happened: in the match-table we have two times the same relation, just inverse: (2,3) and (3,2). I can't constrain this by adding a key or unique constraint, since it would consider it as non redundant. Redundant would be (2,3) and again (2,3).
It seems that this happens when you're making a recursive design, meaning a relation from an entity to itself.

I want that (2,3) is recognised as redundant of (3,2) and therefore forbidden.
Is there any design solution or sql keyword for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constrain Match to have id1<id2, eg

```
alter table Match add constraint ck_StoreEachRelationOnce check (Id1 < Id2)
```